# Can menuTree load a menu's items including children

Tags: navigation

From what I understand I should be able to retrieve all the items in a menu using menuTree. However I only get one level/depth no matter what I try.

My Menu Looks Like:

> Imported Content
> --Products
> ----A Child
> ------Grand Child
> --------Great Grandchild
> ------Grand Child 2
> ----Child 2
> --A Sibling

**Menu structure** (screenshot): https://www.evernote.com/l/AAKdnwekb7BM87AFANo1z2XjCdEvR8HgDEI

This is my code:

```php
  $menu_name = 'imported-content-menu';  
  $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();  
  $parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);  
  $parameters->setMaxDepth(100);  
  $parameters->setMinDepth(0);  
  $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);
```

When I inspect **$tree**, it is an array of two items **"Products"** and **"A Sibling"**.

I inspected these two items to see if there were nested items (the children) but there were not.

The **"Products"** item has **'hasChildren'** set to **TRUE**. But I don't see those children.

Comment: Since hasChildren is true and maxDepth is plenty deep I believe there should be a $tree[%pluginid]->subtree array. However, my subtree array exists but is empty. To debug I took the pluginid for 'Products' and use it in setRoot. I got an empty tree. Maybe my issue is these children can't be loaded for some reason. I am not using access manipulators. Any tips how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the typical route context (`$menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name)`), subtree elements are loaded only, if the menu item is flagged as "Show as expanded" within the menu item settings.

To load the entire tree, you have to pass in a plain MenuTreeParameters object without the current route context:

```
use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeParameters;

$parameters = new MenuTreeParameters();

// Optionally limit to enabled items.
$parameters->onlyEnabledLinks();

// Optionally set active trail.
$menu_active_trail = \Drupal::service('menu.active_trail')->getActiveTrailIds($menu_name);
$parameters->setActiveTrail($menu_active_trail);

// Load the tree.
$tree = \Drupal::menuTree()->load($menu_name, $parameters);
```

Comment: You have no idea how much thanks I have to give! Thank you!!! This was the issue.